# Shaping output array from Caffe segmentation for PIL Image

Tags: python, machine-learning, caffe, coreml

hope everyones day (or night) is going well.

I've been playing around with a Caffe model I came across, and I've been having some trouble working with the output array. I haven't worked with segmentation before so this may be a simple fix for someone more knowledgeable on the subject.

The model is based on this paper [Deep Joint Task Learning for Generic Object Extraction](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~xiaolonw/papers/objextract_nips.pdf). I have converted the model in CoreML format.

The issue I have is this:

When trying to create a PIL image from the output, I get what seems like random noise and I think its just a simple issue of the numpy array being mis-shaped or the order of the pixels is wrong. 
The output array is of shape (2500, 1) and it's supposed to be a 50x50 black and white image

Code looks like this:

```
image = Image.open('./1.jpg')
image = image.resize((55, 55), Image.ANTIALIAS)

predictions = model.predict({'data_55': image} , useCPUOnly = False)
predictions = predictions['fc8_seg']

reshape_array = numpy.reshape(predictions, (50,50))
output_image = Image.fromarray(reshape_array, '1')
```

I've tried both F and C orders on the numpy reshape and can't seem to get anything other than noise that looks like this [image]. I'm using one of the test images provided in the original repo so it shouldn't be a problem. As a side note, the values in the array look like this:

```
[[  4.55798066e-08   5.40980977e-07   2.13476710e-06 ...,   6.66990445e-08
6.81615759e-08   3.21255470e-07]
[  2.69358861e-05   1.94866928e-07   4.71876803e-07 ...,   1.25911642e-10
3.14572794e-08   1.61371077e-08]
```

Any thoughts or answers would be much appreciated and helpful. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Maybe it's a typo but `reshape_array` isn't actually given a value anywhere in the code you posted. Also, have you verified what the output is from the original model for that image? If so, did you also have to reshape the predictions there, or did some other type of postprocessing happen there? The reason I ask is that the output doesn't look random at all but arranged in the wrong order somehow.

Comment: Yeah, missed `reshape_array` when copy pasting. Good catch.

Noise was definitely a bad choice of words on my end. I agree that it does indeed look like the data is there, its just an issue with the formatting of the output data into the image. I wasn't able to run the code from the original project as I don't have the python wrapper for caffe installed. I tried to reverse engineer the post processing code but its a very strange approach and to be honest it didn't make a lot of sense. [Link](https://github.com/xiaolonw/nips14_loc_seg_testonly) to the repo if you're curious

Comment: They save the results from the caffe model into a text file, then load the text file into the post processing. My c++ syntax knowledge is lacking so I had trouble understanding it. I believe the post processing happens in Caffe_Segmentation/examples/seg/dumpRes.cpp

Comment: I suggest you build and install their fork of Caffe, and use that to figure out what the network actually does. Much quicker than guessing. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I've spent a significant amount of time trying to get it to build with no luck :( Thanks for the help though! Much appreciated. I'm going to dig through the scripts they are using and see if I can understand the method they are using to write the data to the txt file then convert it to an image later. Maybe this will force me to learn a bit more about C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was able to figure this out. It wasn't an issue with the order of the array, but with the values and data type. Here is the code I put together to get a proper image from the output.

```
predictions = model.predict({'data_55': image} , useCPUOnly = True) # Run the prediction

map_final = predictions['fc8_seg'][0,0,:,:] # fc8_seg is the output of the neural network
map_final = map_final.reshape((50,50)) # Reshape the output from shape (2500) to (50, 50)
map_final = numpy.flip(map_final, 1) # Flip axis 1 to unmirror the image

# Scale the values in the array to a range between 0 and 255
map_final -= map_final.min() 
map_final /= map_final.max()
map_final = numpy.ceil(map_final*255)

map_final_unint8 = map_final.astype(numpy.uint8) # Convert the data type to an uint8
pil_image = Image.fromarray(map_final_unint8, mode = 'L') # Create the PIL image
```

And the output:

[image: And the output]

Everything looks just as it should!